# Chisel variable Declaration Syntax Meaning rvs: Bool*

Tags: chisel

Looking at object DecoupledHelper and class DecoupledHelper code, I see the following.

```
object DecoupledHelper {
 def apply(rvs: Bool*) = new DecoupledHelper(rvs)
}

class DecoupledHelper(val rvs: Seq[Bool]) {
 def fire(exclude: Bool, includes: Bool*) = {

   (rvs.filter(_ ne exclude) ++ includes).reduce(_ && _)
 }
}
```

I don't understand the parameters declaration syntax in apply method. (`rvs: Bool*`). What is the meaning of `*` at end of Type **Bool**.
Looking at constructor parameters of class DecoupledHelper, it expects (`rvs: Seq[Bool]`)

Does this mean that type `Bool*` is automatically converted to type `Seq[Bool]`?

While at this, can anyone also explain what rvs.filter method is doing?

Comment: That’s Scala’s syntax for functions with variable number of arguments. More info here: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-define-methods-variable-arguments-varargs-fields

Answer (score 0):

As Kamyar said, `Type*` is the Scala syntax for variable number of arguments (also known as "varags"). It let's you call the `DecoupledHelper` `apply` method like so:

```scala
val helper = DecoupledHelper(a, b, c) // calling apply on the companion object
// instead of
val helper2 = new DecoupledHelper(Seq(a, b, c)) // calling constructor of the class
```

For those new to Chisel and Scala, note that [`apply` is a special function Scala](https://madusudanan.com/blog/scala-tutorials-part-15-the-apply-method/) that is called when you "apply" parentheses to an object or instance. Thus `DecoupledHelper(a, b, c)` is equivalent to `DecoupledHelper.apply(a, b, c)`.

> While at this, can anyone also explain what rvs.filter method is doing?

It is taking advantage of the implementation of Chisel which I would not recommend doing. [`ne`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.10/scala/AnyRef.html#ne(x$1:AnyRef):Boolean) is the Scala function for not referentially equal. It lets you check if two object are not the same object in memory.

In this case, it let's you do things like the following:

```scala
val helper = DecoupledHelper(a, b, c)
helper.fire()   // a && b && c
helper.fire(b)  // a && c
```

Now because this is dangerously using referential equality instead of actual hardware equality (and there are limitations of the implementation that motivated this), something that *should* work does not:

```scala
val helper = DecoupledHelper(a, b, c)
val d = b           // Same reference
val e = WireInit(b) // Equivalent Wire but different reference
helper.fire(d)  // a && c
helper.fire(e)  // a && b && c
```

`d` points to the same object on the heap as `b`, but `e` does not despite the fact that it is equivalent from the hardware perspective.

For more information, see the related bug report and discussion: https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip/issues/1616